# Simulate click-and-drag with a Griffin PowerMate

Tags: macos

Is there any way to simulate a click-and-drag with a [Griffin PowerMate](https://store.griffintechnology.com/desktop/powermate) on Mac OS X? I would want the click-and-drag to be bound to a rotation of the device, so it would have to respond to repeated actions, but would be a single click-and-drag throughout the rotation.

Comment: What is being clicked and dragged?

Comment: @emb1995: A knob on one of the instruments on [Audiotool](http://audiotool.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me a bunch of research, and it can be done.

[This video example](http://vimeo.com/5412630) may help, in addition to [the CTRL8 manual](http://www.chromedecay.org/downloads/CTRL/CTRL_manual.pdf).

[This is the original article](http://www.chromedecay.org/2009/07/02/announcing-ctrl4-ctrl8-midi-control-for-griffin-powermate-puredata/) that outlines how PowerMate can become a MIDI device.

1. Install a program called [PureData](http://puredata.info/community/projects/software/pd-extended), extended version *This is your PowerMate interpreter*
2. Configure the PowerMate by following the [CTRL8 manual](http://www.chromedecay.org/downloads/CTRL/CTRL_manual.pdf)
3. Open The CTRL4/CTRL8 patch, which can be found [here in a zip file](http://www.chromedecay.org/downloads/CTRL/PowerMate_CTRL.zip)
4. Open audiotool
5. Add the CTRL8 MIDI device
6. Assign your knobs

Comment: I would rather not have to use MIDI because I don't want to have to assign a control each time I want to use a knob.

Comment: Audiotool doesn't support any other method of communication at this time. The developers just haven't included it. Even still, the problem with the PowerMate is that it is restricted in it's software. Please don't take me for a downer, I would love to see OSC support natively with the PowerMate, and OSC support with audiotool, but the software just doesn't exist. The only other suggestion I have for you is to leave some feedback on the burnstudios website.

Comment: Alright, sounds like this is the only solution then. I have opened a feature request for changing the selected control's value with a keyboard shortcut. But I guess this will work for now. +200 rep for you, sir!